# Why is there no error comparing Vector and Array in Rust?

Tags: arrays, vector, rust, equality

I know that Array and Vector are different types in Rust language, but I wonder why there is no error in comparing the two.

```
// Rust Programming Language
fn main() {
    let vec = vec!["a", "b", "c"];  // Vector
    let arr = ["a", "b", "c"];      // Array
    println!("{}", vec == arr);     // true!                                                 
}
```

Comment: Because `Vec` [implements `PartialEq<[U; N]>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-PartialEq%3C%5BU%3B%20N%5D%3E).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [`Vec<T>` implements `PartialEq<[T; N]>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.61.0/src/alloc/vec/partial_eq.rs.html#36), allowing you to compare vectors with array.

You can overload the equality operators in Rust by implementing the [`PartialEq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html) trait, and it takes an (optional, defaulted to `Self`) generic parameter to allow you to specify different type for the left side (`Self`, the implementing type) and the right side (the generic parameter, by default the same).

Answer (score 3):

The `==` operator works on any type that implements the [`PartialEq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html) trait. The trait can be implemented for different types for the left and the right side. In this case, `Vec<T>` implements the trait for [all of these slice types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-PartialEq%3C%26%27_%20%5BU%3B%20N%5D%3E):

```
PartialEq<&'_ [U; N]>
PartialEq<&'_ [U]>
PartialEq<&'_ mut [U]>
PartialEq<[U; N]>
PartialEq<[U]>
```

The array in your code has the type `[&str; 3]`, which matches `[U; N]` and therefore this works.